# Proving Taylor's expansion of sin x

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I am currently trying to prove Taylor's theorem of sin(x) using $(\cos x+i\sin x)^n$. I have managed to progress quite a bit, however, I am wondering how to proceed with the following:
${n \choose 2k+1}(\sin\theta)^{(2k+1)}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-2k)}{(2k+1)(2k)...1}(\sin\theta)^{(2k+1)}$
Also, from prev. calculations I have that n tends to infinity and n,k are both natural numbers where k starts from 0.Also, I assumed that n is odd earlier.Finally, I wish to prove it without prior knowledge of Taylor series of cos(x) and sin(x) ( i.e. I can't use ${e^{ix}=\cos(x)+isin(x)}$).
Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: The *logic* path for this is using $\cos x+i\sin x = e^{ix} = \sum\cdots$

Comment: Thanks but I forget to mention that I cannot use complex exponential formula.

Comment: Then, I can't understand the usefulness of $\cos x+i\sin x$. The other logic path is calculating the successive derivatives of $\sin$.

Comment: Are you aware that $\sin ^{(n)}\ne\sin^n$?